# CircularImageView with a solid color

Tags: android, view, android-imageview

The CircularImageView, https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView, works great when setting an image bitmap like so...

`circularImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

However, there are times where I just want to set a solid color instead of a bitmap. If I do something like this,

`circularImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);`

The color of the view is set but the image is never made circular, so it fill the entire rectangular view. I'm assuming the `getDrawable()` is returning null so it can't actually manipulate the view. Anyone ran into this problem or any suggestions on what to do?

Edit:

I can do this but it seems a bit flimsy:

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
image.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
circularImageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call `circularImageView.setImageResource(R.color.blue)` instead.

The code you wrote sets the background of the view, not the content image. Looking at the code on github, this view will only clip the content image to the circle--it has no effect on the background at all.

Comment: The CircularImageView class gets the Drawable via `getDrawable()` but crashes at `Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` because the width and height are 0. Looks like I'll have to specify a width and height which is what I was doing in my Edit (above).

Answer (score 1):

Give a try for `ColorDrawable`;

```
int decode = Integer.decode("FF6666");
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(decode);
```

Comment: Doesn't work if I do `circularImageView.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(R.color.blue))` also `setBackground(Drawable)` is deprecated.

Comment: yeah setBackground is deprecated for newer api levels, instead you should use setBackgroundDrawable(), also it should work because ColorDrawable is subclass of Drawable